# issue with bundling and minification in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have bundled the required libraries as following.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/libraries").Include(
                        "~/Content/js/jquery.1.10.2.js",
                        "~/Content/js/jquery.ui.1.10.3.js",
                        "~/Content/js/angular.js",
                        "~/Content/js/ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js",
                        "~/Content/js/ng-dialog.0.1.6.js",
                        "~/Content/js/underscore.1.5.0.js",
                        "~/Content/js/jquery.easyWizard.js",
                        "~/Content/js/bootstrap.js"));
```

and referred it as `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/libraries")` in the `_Layout` but I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

and Angular is not getting loaded.

The following code works:

```
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.ui.1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Angular/ng-grid-2.0.11.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/ng-dialog.0.1.6.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/underscore.1.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/botstrap.js.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/jquery.easyWizard.js"></script>
```

Where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe when you add multiple files in a bundle, the ordering may not be in the order you specified it. To ensure an exact order, you would have to create your own [bundle orderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ibundleorderer%28VS.110%29.aspx).

The easier way is to separate out your bundles so you can specify them in the exact order in your **cshtml** files. Also, some tips. Use **{version}** in your file name wherever you can, makes life easier when you get a new version of the file and use `Bundle` instead of `ScriptBundle` if there is already a minified version in the directory. It will use that instead of running the minifier for it again.

So do something like this:

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");

bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
// etc...
```

Then in your *_Layout.cshtml* file, specify `~/bundles/jquery` first, then the others in the order of the dependencies.